# Prove $\;\log_2 (1-t^3+O(1/n))=\log_2(1-t^3)+O(1/n)$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I read this today and I'm having trouble proving it:

$$\log_2 (1-t^3+O(1/n))=\log_2(1-t^3)+O(1/n)$$

It is also said that it works for $0\le t\le 1/2$. How to derive this bound?

I know that $\log(1+x)=O(x)$ for $|x|\lt1$ but I'm not being able to apply it.

Comment: Are $t$ and $n$ related? (If not, this follows because your function has bounded derivative on the stated interval, and so is Lipschitz continuous.) In any case, $0 \leq t \leq 1/2$ looks like a _sufficient_ condition, not a _necessary and sufficient_ condition; that is, you don't derive this condition, you just need to see that "it works".

Comment: No, $t$ and $n$ are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$\log_2 (1-t^3+O(1/n))=\log_2(1-t^3)+O(1/n)$$
$$\log_2 (1-t^3+O(1/n)) - \log_2(1-t^3)=O(1/n)$$
$$\log_2 (\frac{1-t^3+O(1/n)}{1-t^3})=O(1/n)$$
$$\log_2 (1 + \frac{1}{1-t^3}O(1/n))=O(1/n)$$

Considering that $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}$, the biggest value $\frac{1}{1-t^3}$ can take is $\frac{8}{7}$. That is $O(1)$.

$$\log_2 (1 + O(1)O(1/n))=O(1/n)$$
$$\log_2 (1 + O(1/n))=O(1/n)$$

Now you can apply your identity.